# I want to have a unique field which should not be unique when combining together with another field

Tags: database, database-design

**e.g.:**

```
Let's say I have a table containing three fields, id, user_id & id_proof_number. Then,
```

*Accepted:*
**id**: 1,
**user_id**: 1,
**id_proof_number**: 123456789012,

*Accepted*:
**id**: 2,
**user_id**: 1,
**id_proof_number**: 123456789012,

*Not Accepted*:
**id**: 3,
**user_id**: 2,
**id_proof_number**: 123456789012

**Can someone tell me how to do this?**

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/42469/109860

Comment: Tell you how to do what? This is unintelligible.  Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS If subrows values under some set of columns are unique then subrows under a superset of those columns must be unique. PS Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Please don't use code block format or quote block format for emphasis. Just write clearly.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have user_id and id_proof_number that should be unique by itself but not refeering both.

In your example you should implement something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.User
ADD CONSTRAINT uniqueFields UNIQUE (user_id, id_proof_number)
```

In accord with the Primary Key definition, **id** should be unique indipendently by other fields.